# Match partial and whole words in any order

Tags: regex, typescript

I would like to be able to catch strings like:

user input into search field:

```
Grey box
```

And in a list there should be a match with:

```
Grey Boxing Gloves
Grey Window Box
Box with Grey Paint
```

This should not match:

```
Greater boxing gloves
```

Attempts:

`(?=.*\b\w*\b).+`

Comment: Why the latter should not be a match?

Comment: @revo it shouldnt matter in what order you search the string in. Hope that clears it up :)

Comment: which lang you're using? post your attempts..

Comment: Sorry, why `greyer boxing` shouldn't be a match but `grey boxing` should be?

Comment: @revo You're correct. My bad. I'll correct. Greyer should match

Comment: Fine. Please update your requirements and show your attempts.

Comment: @revo Hope it's more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Is it javascript?

Comment: @revo yes. Typescript to be exact.

Comment: How is your attempt `(?=.*\b\w*\b).+` connected to user input?

Comment: @Arkadiy `boolean = (Object.match(new RegExp('(?=.*\b\w*\b).+');`

Comment: How about "Allgrey Boxing"? Should that match?

Comment: @Arkadiy no, because there is nothing called `allgrey` (if that makes sense) :D

Comment: @Joel, please  update your question. Also, what is filterStringDesc ? Just provide the regexp you generated for your example.

Comment: @Arkadiy it's just an empty string. ` filterStringDesc ="";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be using positive lookaheads. They don't consume characters, hence order doesn't matter. If query being searched is `Grey box` regex will look like:

```
^(?=.*Grey)(?=.*box)
```

I wrote a code snippet to build a regex regardless of number of words within it. But take care, query should pass a filtering / quoting process before being used in a regex:

```js
var query = "Grey box";

var list = ['Grey Boxing Gloves',
'Grey Window Box',
'Box with Grey Paint',
'Greater boxing gloves']

// You should filter `query` before building regex
var re = '^(?=.*' + query.split(/\s+/).join(')(?=.*') + ')';

list.forEach(function(x){
   if (x.match(new RegExp(re, 'i'))) {
      console.log(x);
   }
})
```

Comment: So in other words: `^(?=.*\w*)(?=.*\w*)` ?

Comment: `\w*` should replace words in your query.

Comment: have a look here. It doesn't seem to match anything. https://regexr.com/3q1no

Comment: Did you run code snippet in the answer? Also see here https://regex101.com/r/mkAESb/1 I'm not sure about regexr behavior.

Comment: Yes. Anyhow, i verified that `(?=.*\w*)(?=.*\w*)` gives me the correct results now on my end.